# Error in calling web API in asp .net web forms status code 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> I have created web API that is working fine  as i checked that, but the problem is when i call that web API in asp .net website here is a code below of calling web API

```
protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50653/");

    HClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    BoiMember obj = new BoiMember();
    obj.CustomerId = txt_customerid.Text.Trim();
    obj.AadhaarNo = txt_aadharno.Text.Trim();
    obj.CustomerName = txt_name.Text.Trim();
    obj.AccountNo = txt_accountno.Text.Trim();
    obj.MobileNo = txt_mobile.Text.Trim();
    obj.branchcd = Session["BranchCode"].ToString();
    obj.ZoneCode = Session["ZoneCode"].ToString();
    obj.Campcd = "1";
    obj.ind = 1;
    obj.SourceType = 2;
    obj.UserId = Session["UserName"].ToString();
    string uri = "api/BoiMember/GetRecord/";
    var response = HClient.GetAsync(uri+obj).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var GetData = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<BoiMember>>().Result;
        GvdRecords.DataSource = GetData;
        GvdRecords.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

> Where in the API controller named **BoiMemberController** when I call this web API without parameters it works fine but as I Pass parameters I get the status code 404 Error not found. My web APIConfig.cs has a code

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate:  "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Why are you doing `uri+obj`? That is not going to result in a valid url. What does it produce?

Comment: Even if you serialized `obj` to a string an used `uri + '/' + obj` it would not make much sense - how would you use it?

Answer (score 1):

By default when you do `[some object].ToString()` the `ToString` method returns the objects type. So you are probably passing a string similar to `api/BoiMember/GetRecord/BoiMember` (not sure on the fully qualified type). You need to build up the uri using string formatting. Here is a basic example with 2 parameters:

```
var uri = string.Format("api/BoiMember/GetRecord/?customerId={0}&aadhaarNo={1}"
, txt_customerid.Text.Trim()
, txt_aadharno.Text.Trim());
```

This assumes that your parameters are query string parameters. If you have a web api with the parameter positioned inside the url then you need to change the structure of the string accordingly.

You should also have null checks if necessary and also if a parameter if empty you might not want to send it to the api.

Comment: thanx @Igor this worked but can i pass object as a parameters

Comment: @AmitYadav - not in an GET or DELETE. With Post/Put you can but you must serialize them using a serializer (usually to JSON or XML). There are many tutorials on how to do this with HttpClient.